# Supress `missing required architecture i386` warning for Optional Frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, llvm

I have some Framework linked as ***OPTIONAL*** (using camera), so it won't compile for Simulator, which is great. The app builds, runs fine on Simulator.

Is there any way to supress `missing required architecture i386` warning when build for Simulator?

---

Full warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file <WhateverFramework>, missing required architecture i386 in file <WhateverFramework> (2 slices)
```

Comment: Please post the full warning.

Comment: @Undo There it goes. The point is that it has slices for `armv6`, `armv7`, but not any for `i386`. The app builds, runs fine, I just want to supress the warning, thats all.

Comment: i think you are missing a framework

Comment: @XCodeMonkey I'm **excluding it by intention** for iOS Simulator. The app builds, runs fine. I just want to ***SUPRESS THE WARNING***.

Comment: try creating a universal library through terminal. this terminal command will create a universal library:
lipo -create lib_arm.a lib_i386.a -output lib_universal.a

Comment: I have no access for the source. This is a third party framework that works only with camera, there is no plan to support Simulator on their roadmap - they told. Results in quirky workaronds on my side. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "Optional" framework is optional at runtime only. It is required to be present at build time.

You can use platform-specific build settings to avoid linking to that framework at all in simulator builds.